# Filter datadog logs in the local agent before sending

Tags: datadog

I use datadog agent 6.9 that run on my host(not on a docker), 
and i also run several application on my host (docker images).

I try to avoid sending specific logs to the datadoghq from my mongodb. 
So according to https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/log_collection/?tab=tailexistingfiles
I create mongo.d directory and conf.yaml inside that look like:

```
init_config:
instances:
  # Specify the MongoDB URI, with database to use for reporting (defaults to "admin")
  # E.g. mongodb://datadog:LnCbkX4uhpuLHSUrcayEoAZA@localhost:27016/my-db
  - server: mongodb://datadog:LnCbkX4uhpuLHSUrcayEoAZA@localhost:27016/my-db
    # Controls connectTimeoutMS, serverSelectionTimeoutMS and socketTimeoutMS (see http://api.mongodb.com/python/3.4.0/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html)
    # Defaults to 30 seconds
    # timeout: 30

    # tags:
    #   - optional_tag1
    #   - optional_tag2

    # Whether or not to read from available replicas (default true).
    # Disable this if any replicas are inaccessible to the agent.
    replica_check: true

    # Optional SSL parameters, see https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/2.6.3/pymongo/mongo_client.py#L193-L212
    # for more details
    #
    # ssl: True # Optional (default to False)
    # ssl_keyfile: # Path to the private keyfile used to identify the local
    # ssl_certfile: # Path to the certificate file used to identify the local connection against mongod.
    # ssl_cert_reqs: 0 # Specifies whether a certificate is required from the other side of the connection, and whether it will be validated if provided.
    # Possible values:
    #   * 0 for ssl.CERT_NONE (certificates ignored)
    #   * 1 for ssl.CERT_OPTIONAL (not required, but validated if provided)
    #   * 2 for ssl.CERT_REQUIRED (required and validated)
    # ssl_ca_certs: #  Path to the ca_certs file
    #
    # By default, the check collects a sample of metrics from MongoDB.
    # The (optional) `additional_metrics` parameter instructs the check to collect additional
    # metrics on specific topics.
    # Available options are:
    # * `metrics.commands` - Use of database commands
    # * `tcmalloc` -  TCMalloc memory allocator
    # * `top` - Usage statistics for each collection
    # * `collection` - Metrics of the specified collections
    additional_metrics:
      - metrics.commands
      - tcmalloc
      - top
      - collection
    #
    # Collect metrics on specific collections from the database specified
    # Requires `additional_metrics.collection` to be present
    # Metrics such as `mongodb.collection.count` will be collected for each named collection and tagged as follows:
    #   - `db:<dbname>` e.g. `db:my-db`
    #   - `collection:<collection-name>` e.g. `collection:my_collection`
    # Each collection generates many metrics,
    # up to 8 + the number of indices on the collection for each collection
    collections:
  - apples
  - oranges
# Collect indexes access metrics for every index in every collections in
# the 'collections' list. This is available starting mongo 3.2.
# collections_indexes_stats: false

## Log section (Available for Agent >=6.0)

logs:

    # - type : (mandatory) type of log input source (tcp / udp / file)
    #   port / path : (mandatory) Set port if type is tcp or udp. Set path if type is file
    #   service : (mandatory) name of the service owning the log
    #   source : (mandatory) attribute that defines which integration is sending the logs
    #   sourcecategory : (optional) Multiple value attribute. Can be used to refine the source attribtue
    #   tags: (optional) add tags to each logs collected

    # - type: file
    #   path: /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log
    #   service: mongo
    #   source: mongodb
    - type: docker
      service: mongo
      source: mongodb
      log_processing_rules:
      - type: exclude_at_match
        name: exclude_mongo
        pattern: (?s).*
```

But when i restart my agent it's still send the unwanted logs to my datadoghq.

Thanks in advance for the help,
Baruch

Comment: which logs do you want to collect vs. not want to collect? what do the unwanted logs start with? might just be a matter of getting the regex pattern right. (also, have you checked that it's valid yaml? i'm looking at that `source:mongo` wishing it was a `source: mongo`, and also that everything following `log_processing_rules:` was indented 2 spaces further. Might not be that though.)

Comment: Hi,
You're right i have mistake in the source and i need to add space. But in my server the yaml is correct. thank for the quick response and i hope you could help me with my problem

Comment: Hmmm yeah I think it might just be the pattern. For the logs that you want to exclude, what do they start with?

Comment: Hi, I check the pattern in the regex checker and it’s work fine. I send to datadog support all my findings and they recommended to add the filter string to the label in the docker compose file(of every docker image that I want to filter) it’s work with my pattern but I need to build again my docker images instead of adding conf.yaml to the datadog conf.d folder but it’s doesn't work. Any advice?

Comment: Is the regex fine with golang regex? I think I'd have to see an example start of a log line in order to be much help.